# How to print a Powershell variable in Python?

Tags: python, powershell, variables

How can I pass Powershell variables to Python and the print it?

---

*Powershell: (test.ps1)*

```
$var1 = "Hello"
$var2 = "How are u?"

return $var1
return $var2
```

How can I now print one or both variables in Python?
When I do this I **obviously just get the first one**. But how can I just print *$var2* or *both*?

*Python:*

```
p = repr(subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "C:\\Users\\z003tjra\\test.ps1"],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
print(p)
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `return $var1, $var2`?

Comment: You should respond to comments as opposed to [deleting your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59049094/1324033)

Comment: @Karl yes I did

Comment: @Saysexes of course. I just asked the question in a wrong wy